# Cakephp controller action does not redirect on live server

Tags: cakephp, redirect

I have a action to save data in 4 models. Here is my controller code. I do get any error for saving data, I double checked it, But this action does not redirect to given url after it saves data, all it shows is a blank page of same action (action which is used to save data). This problem is only on live server. In my local copy is just working fine.

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //First upload user pic
            if ($this->request->data['FacilityResident']['pic']['name'] != NULL) {
                $pic = $this->request->data['FacilityResident']['pic']['tmp_name'];
                if (!is_dir(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'residents' . DS)) {
                    mkdir(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'residents' . DS);
                    chmod(WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'residents' . DS, 0777);
                }
                $uniq = mt_rand();
                move_uploaded_file($pic, WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'residents' . DS . $this->request->data['FacilityResident']['pic']['name']);
                $this->request->data['FacilityResident']['avatar'] = DS . 'residents' . DS . $this->request->data['FacilityResident']['pic']['name'];
                unset($this->request->data['FacilityResident']['pic']);
            }

            $this->request->data['FacilityResident']['facilities_id'] = $this->Session->read('urlparam.facilityId');
            $this->FacilityResident->save($this->request->data['FacilityResident']);
            $residentId = $this->FacilityResident->getLastInsertID();
            if (!empty($this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']['diet'])) {
                $dietData = implode(',', $this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']['diet']);
                unset($this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']['diet']);
                $this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']['diet'] = $dietData;
            }
            $this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']['facility_residents_id'] = $residentId;
            $this->FacilityResidentDietary->save($this->request->data['FacilityResidentDietary']);
            $this->request->data['ResidentMealschedule']['facility_residents_id'] = $residentId;
            $this->ResidentMealschedule->save($this->request->data['ResidentMealschedule']);
            $residentMealSchedultId = $this->ResidentMealschedule->getLastInsertID();
            foreach ($this->request->data['Mealdetail'] as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'Bread') {
                    $value[0]['attribute_four'] = implode(',', array_filter($value[0]['attribute_four']));
                }
                foreach ($value as $val) {
                    $this->Mealdetail->saveAll($val);
                    $data['Mealschedule']['meal_types_id'] = 1;
                    $data['Mealschedule']['resident_mealschedule_id'] = $residentMealSchedultId;
                    $data['Mealschedule']['mealdetails_id'] = $this->Mealdetail->getLastInsertID();
                    $this->Mealschedule->saveAll($data);
                }
                unset($data);
                unset($val);
            }
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($this->request->data['ResidentMealMeta'] as $key => $val) {
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$i]['resident_mealschedule_id'] = $residentMealSchedultId;
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$i]['meal_value'] = $key;
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$i]['meal_option'] = $val;
                $i++;
            }
            if (!empty($this->request->data['ResidentTray']['tray'][0])) {
                $j = count($data['ResidentMealMeta']) + 1;
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$j]['meal_value'] = 'tray';
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$j]['resident_mealschedule_id'] = $residentMealSchedultId;
                $data['ResidentMealMeta'][$j]['meal_option'] = implode(',', $this->request->data['ResidentTray']['tray']);
            }
            unset($this->request->data['ResidentMealMeta']);
            unset($this->request->data['ResidentTray']);
            if ($this->ResidentMealMeta->saveAll($data['ResidentMealMeta'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('New resident added', 'flash', array('alert' => 'success'));
                if(isset($url)){
                    unset($url);
                }
                $url = Router::url(array(
                            'controller' => 'residents',
                            'action' => 'resident_list',
                            '?' => array('facility_name' => $this->Session->read('urlparam.facilityName'), 'facility_id' => $this->Session->read('urlparam.facilityId'))
                ));
                $this->redirect($url);
            }
        }
```

can any one here tell me what is going wrong? I have also tried saving data via related model, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this solution :

```
Router::redirect(
    '/controller_where_you_re_saving_data/*',
    array('controller' => 'residents', 'action' => 'resident_list'),
    // view action expects $id as an argument
    array('facility_name' => $this->Session->read('url.facilityName'))
);
```

However , i suggest to not pass the argument when it 's about sessions values , cause you can access to it in every controller in you project , which make the solution like this :

```
Router::redirect(
    '/controller_where_you_re_saving_data/*',
    array('controller' => 'residents', 'action' => 'resident_list'),
  );
```

Here is the document  :
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing

Hope it helps.